# How do I find and edit PHTML files in Magento Go?

Tags: php, css, magento

May I know how do I find and edit PHTML files in Magento Go? Read some places in forums that PHTML files cannot be edited. Wanted to confirm if that's indeed the case.
Saw this on a forum when I was searching on how to get rid of white spaces on the left and right of a product image in the grid view:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/177178/

> Secondly we will have to change the way the image is rendered or
>   displayed when requested by magento, the file we need is `list.phtml`
>   which can be found in
>   `“app/design/frontend/your_theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml”`.
>   First, search for the code below and change the values of;
>   `resize(170), width="170", height="170"` in the values of your image.
>   Resize 170 specify’s height thus if you image is 210x170 it should
>   look like below.

It shows that I have to find and edit the `list.phtml` file, however, I can't seem to find it, less edit it. CSS is fine as I know I can edit the "edit custom.css" under Design Editor in Magento Admin. Can someone please help me regarding the phtml files? Desperately seeking help.

Really appreciate your time and thank you so much in advance!

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: You are correct on not being able to edit .phtml. Changes are locked down to the design editors provided.

Answer (score 0):

Magento Go does not allow you to modify the phtml files.

However, for modifying the dimensions of your images, you can do that according to the Magento Go Documentation.

http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/changing-the-size-of-catalog-images/

1. Go to `Design > Themes Editor > Customize (Theme) > Catalog Images`
2. Modify the dimensions of your images, then save.

Comment: Thanks Axel! Yep I have been modifying the dimensions of the images. However, say when I increase the length and width to 177px instead of 170px, my square image gets cut off on the right. As for my rectangular images of dresses for example, Magento creates a white border on the left and right of the product, and as such the picture is not centred. Perhaps this might give u a better idea: http://www.thesunshinekids.com/new-arrivals.html
That's why I have been playing around with modifying CSS and trying to change PHTML files as well, but to no avail.

Comment: You need to upload your images to the aspect ratio you set, otherwise Magento is going to crop that image to fit into the dimensions you set.  There is no way to modify the functions used to do the cropped because you are using Magento Go.  If it's a requirement to upload images at the incorrect ratios, and modify the functions to comply, you need to use Magento Community edition with your own hosting environment.